# how to remove "more" button in specific form view in openerp? or remove delete option in "more" button

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

There is some options to remove drop down items in more button, I tried in several ways, but i didn't find how to totally hide more button in specific form view.

Comment: you can remove delete option for specific object using security record rules.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I did find that in simple way <form string="Employee" version="7.0" delete="false">

Answer (score 1):

please go to the target form where you want to remove more button and make it like this :

```
   <record id="view_id_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">view.id.form</field>
            <field name="model">model</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form  create="0" delete="0">
                    ...
               </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```